# How to make List<Long> parcelable?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, parcelable

I have a variable of List Long type which I want to save using savedInstanceState. So I need to make it Parcelable. How I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make it `Parcelable`. Use [`putLongArray()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle#putLongArray(java.lang.String,%20long%5B%5D)) to save values and [`getLongArray()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle#getLongArray(java.lang.String)) to retrieve values. If you have a `List<Long>` you'll first have to convert it to a long array.